# PassportJS Google login is erroring, but succeeding

Tags: javascript, passport.js

When I login with Google using PassportJS and `passport-google-oauth20`, my application completes the request successfully, but Passport does not recognize this and calls an error instead.

My code looks like this:

```
router.get('/auth/google/callback',
  passport.authenticate('google', {failureRedirect: '/login'}),
  (req, res) => console.log(req),
  (err, req, res, next) => {
    console.log('test point 1')
    console.log(err.stack)
    return res.status(500).send(err)
  })
```

The output looks like this, indicating that the request did fail I believe:

```
test point 1
undefined
```

But when I check my browser, it returned a 500 code with the **correct Google user information**, such as the profile picture and ID. Passport does not store this in the `req.user` variable that it should either. Thanks!

If it's useful, my passport initialization is pretty simple and clear:

```
// TODO: eventually setup user account system
passport.serializeUser((user, done) => done(null, user))

passport.deserializeUser((obj, done) => done(null, obj))

// TODO: eventually use this to associate the users account
passport.use(new GoogleStrategy({
  callbackURL: 'http://localhost:8080/api/v0/auth/google/callback',
  clientID: 'number-id.apps.googleusercontent.com',
  clientSecret: 'secrets'
}, (accessToken, refreshToken, profile, cb) => {
  cb(profile)
}))
```

The only thing I can think of that would be different about my situation is that I'm only `use`ing passport on a specific set of routes. (e.g. the API)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On this line: `cb(profile)` I was sending an error to the callback instead of the user profile.

It should be this: `cb(null, profile)`.